# Clean architecture - how to implement presenters in MVC

Tags: c#, clean-architecture

According to Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture a use case interactor calls the actual implementation of the presenter (which is injected, following the DIP) to handle the response/display.

How should this be done using C# (ASP.NET Core MVC) ?

Shoud the controller be injected with an C# interfaced usecase which exposes a C# interfaced callback ?

Comment: Please explain this: *Shoud the controller be injected with an C# interfaced usecase which exposes a C# interfaced callback ?* What is a *C# interfaced usecase*?

Comment: My current implementation injects an interactor (aka use-case) as class and an injected presenter class and I call the interactor in a GET operation on the MVC controlller. The result of the interactor is  a response dto. This dto is given to the injected presenter which converts it to a viewmodel. The viewmodel is returned from the GET operation.

Comment: The issue is you are using a lot of *jargon* here such as *interactor* so its hard to understand your qiestion. Could you please post some code so it shows what you are doing?

Comment: I have a feeling that such question is better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CodingYoshi this is jargon specific to that "Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture", so people who don't know what that is are not capable of answering question anyway, so I think it's fine.

Comment: @evk But I use patterns all the time and dont remember their names. Pretty sure with example code, a lot of people would know the answer.

Comment: @Evk when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 4):

In clean architecture presenter and controller are different classes. As u have already described the presenter should be injected into the Interactor. The presenter concerts the Interactor response into the view model which is then passed to the view.

In asp.net MVC this last step involves the controller again which is not 100% as intended by clean architecture but that's how the framework works. So this tiny compromise to make when chosing asp.net MVC.

For more details on this particular question pls reference to my posts here: 
https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/
https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-AspNet/

Comment: The presenter is injected in the Controller, not into the interactor... The missing part for me is how the boundary between usecase and presenter is implemented, should this always be an C# interface ?

Comment: The use case Interactor provides an interface, the output port, which is implemented by the presenter. Through that interface the presenter gets injected into the Interactor (use case)

Comment: Pls have a look at the links I have added to my answer. Examples are in F# but with the diagrams I am sure u can also understand the code with C# background only.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have been interested in documenting the entity boundary interactor (EBI) as descripted by Uncle Bob. There is a [master thesis](https://jyx.jyu.fi/dspace/bitstream/handle/123456789/41024/URN:NBN:fi:jyu-201303071297.pdf) and a more pragmatically but (at the time of writing this post) unfinished documentation aimed at programmers which you can find [here](http://ebi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The idea is also part of the book `Object-Oriented Software Engineering A Use Case Driven Approach` (Refered to as Entity Interface Controller) by `Ivar Jacobson` which Uncle Bob recommends himself in at least one of his talks and a blog post titled [Screaming Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html).

Uncle bob himself gave a [talk](https://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg?t=28m25s) where he explains what he thinks is wrong with web development and why he thinks a different model would be better ([*](https://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg?t=8m59s)):

> The web for all its complexity for all its importance; the web is a
>   detail. It is not the essence of our application, it is an IO channel.
>   Why would we structure our applciation around an IO channel?

He also gives advice on how to structure the application [later on](https://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg?t=28m25s).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the thesis; I could see that the boundaries between usecase and UI are done using C# interfaces (IxxxxResponse) which are resolved using DI but I don't grab the whole picture yet...

Comment: Working in the same area I think the main issue is that Clean Architecture does not match very well with existing web-framework like ASP.Net MVC where the framework is the driver for user input and output. If we like to stay with ASP.Net MVC we have to adapt stuff a little bit an make compromises. I am using MediatR for calling the interactors from the MVC controllers. I guess I will pass the result of the interactors (again using MediatoR) to presenters which build the view-models. Its not exactly what clean-architecture suggests but kind of a compromise so I can still use plain MVC.

Comment: @Marc: MediatR is a great way to apply CQRS where you can attach AOP in a pipeline style